# I create simple login form using python flask, but I cannot redirect to my Home page,

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, flask-wtforms, wtforms

My pycharm ID run window,

```
Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 127-177-535
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\ACER\\PycharmProjects\\wtf-forms\\forms.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 127-177-535
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2021 21:57:38] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2021 21:57:39] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Feb/2021 21:57:39] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I typed **127.0.0.1/login** in my browser and display the login form. When I input data into my form,no error display in my web browser, but cannot redirect to home page.

In my browser console I got this error,

login:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

**This is my python code,**

```
from flask import Flask,redirect,render_template

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

from wtforms import StringField,PasswordField,SubmitField

from wtforms.validators import DataRequired,Email,Length


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email =StringField("Email",validators=[DataRequired(),Email()])
    password = PasswordField("Password",validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=4,max=10)])

    submit =SubmitField("Log In")


app=Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"]="secret"

@app.route("/")
def Home():
    return "Hello World"



@app.route("/login",methods=["POST","GET"])
def Index():
    form=LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
       return redirect("Home")


    return render_template("index.html",form=form)





if __name__ =="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**This is my HTML code,**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {{form.email.label()}}
        {{form.email()}}
        <br><br>
        {{form.password.label()}}
        {{form.password()}}
        <br><br>
        {{form.submit()}}
    
    </form>
    
    
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

** Please help me to fix this error.**

Comment: You should always show the complete error message.

Comment: no error found, but cannot redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem one**

You try to redirect to "Home", which is a function name, but no route.

You can either redirect to "/" or use Flask's `url_for("Home")`.

**Problem two**

You are using `Flask-WTF`, a form framework, which automatically validates your form submissions.

It also protects from so called **CSRF** security issues.

More info about CSRF

https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf

In order to setup CSRF protection, you need to add the following code to your Python code:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

...

csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
```

Make sure you put the line with `csrf` after you instantiated the `app` object.

Then you need to update your HTML code.

Add this to your form

```
    {{ form.csrf_token() }}
```

so it looks like...

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token() }}
    {{form.email.label()}}
    {{form.email()}}
    <br><br>
    {{form.password.label()}}
    {{form.password()}}
    <br><br>
    {{form.submit()}}

</form>
```

Make sure you have updated your code according to both problems, then your app should work - it does on my computer.

**How to solve these kind of problems?**

I used a debugger to find the problem. While I use Flask from time to time, I did not see you missed the CSRF-token at once.

Usually, then I start a debugger and step through the code.

This is not too complicated.

I had a lightning talk at Python Ireland meetup:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fxkco-gS4S8&t=1s&ab_channel=PythonIreland

This is only a couple of minutes but it should explain the basics well enough so you can debug the next problem on your own!

Comment: There is an additional problem in your code, I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Now I can redirect to home page., thanx  for you a explanation.